# Changing the font type for UIpopover tittle

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Please suggest me, how can I  set the font size and font type(as Helvetica-Bold) for the tittle of a UIPopover.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the popover is the navigation controller's title I guess. There is a property called "titleTextAttributes" for UINavigationBar in iOS 5.0 for customization.